# What exactly is a Mercurial changeset?

Tags: mercurial, changeset

If you pull down a changeset are you pulling down the full copy of all files that were changed in the changeset?

Or are you pulling down some type of diff report which Mercurial will then apply to your repo when you do hg update?

Comment: This is a good question. The Wiki link in huntsfromshadow's answer doesn't go far enough for me. It says "A changeset ... is an atomic collection of changes to files in a repository" which supports the answer. However it goes on to list the things that a change set includes, and it doesn't mention that it actually contains diffs. Can anyone else give more explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pulling down a list of changes
for each file.

More details at the site below.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangeSet

Comment: Can you be more specific or give more explanation? See my comment on the question.